# How to stop a button from being clicked again when I press the enter key after clicking it

Tags: javascript, button, events, enter

```
<body>
    <button id="aButton">A button</button>

    <script>
        document.querySelector("#aButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
            console.log("Button clicked!");
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

I have a simple button that logs "Button clicked!" to the console when it is clicked. If I click that button and then press the enter key, the button is clicked again and the "Button clicked!" message is logged to the console a second time. How can I stop that? I don't want the button to be clicked via the enter key, because I will be using the enter key for other purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button will be auto focused after you clicked it. And it will be triggered again after you press the `Enter Key`. You should add `evt.currentTarget.blur();` to prevent this behavior.

```
document.querySelector('#aButton').addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  console.log('Button clicked!');
  evt.currentTarget.blur();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can prevent default when clicked enter key:

```html
<body>
    <button id="aButton">A button</button>

    <script>
        const button = document.querySelector("#aButton");

        button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            console.log("Button clicked!");
        });

        button.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
            // Check if the pressed key is Enter (key code 13)
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                // Prevent the default action (submitting the form)
                event.preventDefault();
                // Prevent the event from propagating further
                event.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```